# Action of surfaceController not hitting

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco7, multisite

I have used multi site with single installation using two content root folder and having different domain/hostname in different folder. So i can access both sites with different template using different url. This is working fine.

Now, I have form where user can fill(on both site). when user submits it saved successfully from both site and a confirmation link is sent to user(works on both site). I am using controller to do accept the form.

And confirmation link is sent to email, now when user clicks on link this needs to be handled by another controller, Now the culprit shows here, when I do it using one domain(url) then it executes successfully but when using another url it doesn't go to the action required. Surprisingly the controller constructor is called and also the overrided index method is also called but another method is not executed.

my controller is as:

```
public class SampleResultContentController : RenderMvcController
{
        private static readonly ILog Logger =
        LogManager.GetLogger(
            MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
        );

    public SampleResultContentController()
        : base()
    {
        Logger.Info("initializing the constructor");

    }

    public override ActionResult Index(Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel model)
    {
        Logger.Info("overriding the base index");
        return base.CurrentTemplate(model);
    }


    public ActionResult SampleConfirmation(RenderModel model)
    {
        Logger.Info("Executing the sample confirmation index");
    }
}
```

the url is "{{domain}}/sample/confirm?token=EDIE3483T7ED23"

Any help please.

Comment: Shouldn't the URL be `{{domain}}/SampleResultContent/confirm?token=EDIE3483T7ED23`?

Comment: I am novice to Umbraco, but this url works with one domain correctly. BTW as I noted the constructor and index method is called. but this method is not only called and the problem occurs with second url only.

Answer (score 0):

For the future reference, it was anwsered in umbraco forum :

So the thing here was something called "hijacking the template" that means actions are called based on the template name,

For more detail
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-controllers

and umbraco forum https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/72079-action-of-surfacecontroller-not-hitting